# Wireless Backhauls

Tags: routing

I'm preparing to install several 5GHz radios at remotes sites in our water district for higher speed backhauls to our SCADA system. I plan to install a partial mesh network with redundant paths to each site. Currently I have 12 separate 900MHz communication lines, each with different subnets (172.18.xxx.xxx). They all repeat back to our HQ on separate subnet lines. The last repeater in the field for each line has multiple remote clients that are all part of that subnet. 
Would a router placed at each repeater allow[image: Backhaul plan] this new backhaul communicate with all subnets (repeaters)?

Comment: A simple diagram would be really helpful. There are a lot of options. You may only need one router at your HQ

Comment: Ask yourself: Can the radios talk to each other or can the radios only talk to HQ? If only HQ then all traffic has to flow through HQ and back out. If they can talk to each other then yes you need a router with a dynamic routing protocol(RIP, OSPF) but your radios would have that capability if they can talk to each other. Post the model info and I'll read the manual for you.